# Uncaught TypeError: "SinkShip" is not a function at window.onload

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and I don't understand why this code is not working?

I want to call a class every time the page is loaded or refreshed.
To test this I added the initialises method to the constructor.
Unfortunately I get this error and I don't understand why:

```
script.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: SinkShip is not a function
    at window.onload
```

This is my .js Code so far.

```
class SinkShip{

    constructor(){
        this.initialies
    }

    initialies(){
        alert('it works');
    }

}

window.onload = (event)=>{
    console.log('HIIIII');
    let SinkShip;
    SinkShip = new SinkShip();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "overriding" your class SinkShip with your variable SinkShip.

Replace `let SinkShip` with `let sinkShip`

```js
class SinkShip {
  constructor() {
    this.initialies();
  }

  initialies() {
    alert("it works");
  }
}

window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log("HIIIII");
  let sinkShip;
  sinkShip = new SinkShip();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In the local scope of your function, `SinkShip` refers to the local variable not the class. To fix use different name for a variable i.e. lowercase `sinkShip` :

```js
class SinkShip {

  constructor() {
    this.initialies();
  }

  initialies() {
    alert('it works');
  }

}

window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('HIIIII');
  let sinkShip = new SinkShip();
};
```